# Diagrama ER especificar opciones posibles de un atributo

Tags: base-de-datos

mi consulta esta relacionada cuando el atributo de una entidad puede tomar opciones conocidas como valor. ¿Esto puede especificarse o se generaliza?
En el siguiente diagrama modelo una regla de negocio que refiere a que un animal tiene un tipo de alimentación (herbívora, carnívora u omnívora) y que un mineral puede ser cristal o roca. Esto lo generalize como tipo alimentacion y tipo mineral ¿es correcto?. Desde ya muchas gracias.

[image: Imagen diagrama]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu pregunta estás planteando un modelo ER más o menos así:

[image: Modelado ER]

En el que acabarás propagando, por esa cardinalidad 1:N, el campo `id_tipo_alimento` a la tabla `animales`, prescindiendo de `alimentan`, una vez que pases al modelo relacional. De ahí que intentes modelarlo directamente como un atributo en el modelo ER, con lo que perderías esa posibilidad de restringir a tipos de alimentación predefinidos.

Yo no lo veo como especialización ni como generalización, sino como una simple relación de cardinalidad 1:N. Son conceptos diferentes.